# Azure Marketplace SaaS API Client

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

We want to use marketplace's fulfillment API in a .NET application (Visual Studio 2013 with .NET Framework 4.7.2). We are trying to install the package using the NuGet package manager, but it gives us the error like below:

```
Adding 'AzureMarketplaceSaaSApiClient 3.5.1' to app.
Uninstalling 'AzureMarketplaceSaaSApiClient 3.5.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'AzureMarketplaceSaaSApiClient 3.5.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'AzureMarketplaceSaaSApiClient 3.5.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact 
the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package AzureMarketplaceSaaSApiClient
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Any suggestions on which framework we need to install this package?

Comment: If you check the package page on nuget.org https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureMarketplaceSaaSApiClient/ you can see that this package targets NETStandard 2.1. NETStandard 2.1 is only compatible with  DotNet Core 3.0 or later.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have tried to open this using VS 2019 with DotNetCore 3.0 and it works for me. I want to use Saas fulfillment API in the Asp.net framework 4.7. Do you have an idea about which Package will help me?